# PostgreSQL database considering the script as ANSI instead of UTF8

Tags: sql, postgresql, utf-8, ansi

I have executed a script that updates a column in a database and that worked well.
The script would be having an update statement as below. It is trying to update the `display_name` with an inverted comma in it.

```
Update table1
Set display_name = 'I'm Kumar'
Where internal_name = 'IK';
```

When I executed the same script in another database, it is updating the display name with some special character in place of an inverted comma. Seems like the script is being considered as Ansi encoded format instead of `UTF-8` format.

Please help me to understand why is this happening. Will there be any setting at the database level to change.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and that setting is `client_encoding`.

The default value is specified in the server configuration, and the client has to override it if desired:

```
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
```

Comment: Thanks for this info. I just looked at the existing client_encoding. It is already set to UTF-8. Is there anything else that I can look at?

Comment: What is the encoding of the script?

Comment: Are you sure that `client_encoding` is set to `UTF8` in the script's connection? Testing with a different connection is not good enough. Perhaps you should include the `SET` command in the script. Then, if the script is really encoded in UTF-8, nothing can possibly go wrong.

Comment: I just tried executing the script from PSQL CMD and it went well. It didn't create unwanted character this time.